# How come string "model_year" is not the same as the string "model_year"

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with a php script where two strings are not the same as each other.   It goes something like this:

```
echo $s1; // echoes model_year
echo md5($s1); // echoes 7dd909a04b17a0f9ce4c3a975d70e275
echo $s2; // echoes model_year
echo md5($s2); // echoes 0b42417a9f183a2321b39f1caecd56aa
```

Why is the string `model_year` not the same as the string `model_year` ?  The variable `$s1` was hard coded into the php file.  The variable `$s2` is populated via content from a csv file.  I also did a var_dump of both here:

```
echo var_dump($s1); // echoes string(10) "model_year" 
echo var_dump($s2); // echoes string(13) "model_year"
```

Comment: Does one or the other have trailing whitespace?

Comment: Do `var_dump($s1)`. I guess you have some whitespaces in your variable or html tags which you don't see if you don't do: Right click -> view source code

Comment: maybe different encodings?

Comment: echo $s1 === $s2; to see if they are indeed identical

Comment: @Rizier123 - ok i just did a var dump, one has string(10) and the other has string(13).  View source doesn't show any whitespace or tags or anything.

Comment: @insanebits if it is encoding issue, what can I do to make them the same?

Comment: @John This-> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php Look if they are the same

Comment: OK looks like s1 is using ASCII and s2 is using UTF-8.  That's probably the problem.

Comment: @John Try this: `$s2= iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII, $s2);`

Comment: iconv() doesn't seem to do anything.  $s2 stays the same encoding as it was before.

Comment: @John Maybe try the other way around since ASCII is already valid UTF-8: `$s1= iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $s1);`

Comment: @Rizier123 - ok finally got it working.  I did what you suggested, convert s1 to ASCII.  But I also had to re-save my CSV file as UTF-8 without BOM.  When the CSV file was UTF-8 with BOM, $s1 kept remaining as UTF-8.

Comment: @John You got it working that is all what matters :D

Answer (score -1):

You have a trailing space at the end of `$s2`. User `trim()` function like:

```
$s1 = "model_year";
$s2 = "model_year ";
echo $s1; // echos model_year
echo md5($s1); // echos 7dd909a04b17a0f9ce4c3a975d70e275 
echo md5($s2); // echos 0b42417a9f183a2321b39f1caecd56aa
echo md5(trim($s2)); // echos 7dd909a04b17a0f9ce4c3a975d70e275
```

[**EXAMPLE PHP FIDDLE**](https://eval.in/290929)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "model_year " is "fad911fb1340fa35f9ae1565a213fd7f"

Comment: Your answer is right, but "model_year " does NOT md5 to a string that starts with "0b424 ...". So the `trim()` is doing more than only removing a space.

Comment: @JeroenJK I think you missed the `$s1` It doesn't have `trim()` applied to it and the resulting md5 hash is `7dd909a04b17a0f9ce4c3a975d70e275` which is the same after applying `trim()` to `$s2`.

Comment: *You have a trailing space at the end of $s2* No he did not! it was a encoding problem.

Comment: @Rizier123 I put it intentionally to compare the resulting md5. That is why I echoed 3 md5 strings. Anyways it was encoding problem which converted it to the exact md5 string interestingly.